# C print text lines and update them

Tags: c, printing, printf

I have a program in C that print a table. I want update the values of this table without reprint the entire table. I can update one line with `\r` character, but how I can update more than one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about outputing the table to stdout which is directed to a console (terminal). There is no standard way of manipulating the terminal in C because its presence it's not even required for standard output to work (it might be very well directed to a file, for example).

There are, however, multi-platform libraries such as ncurses that can operate on a terminal. You might consider using them.